# Jquery .on('click', function() toggle between 3 classes depending on current class

Tags: jquery

I am working on a button with class 'grid' that switches between 3 classes, it will always start with class '16pads' when the page is loaded, then when clicked it should remove the class '16pads' and replace it with '36pads' then if the button is clicked again and hasClass '36pads' it should remove the class '36pads' and replace it with '64pads'. Lastly if the button has class '64pads' and it is clicked it should remove the class '64pads' and replace it with '16pads' it is basically looping through the 3 classes when the button is clicked.

For some reason when clicked it seems to loop through the entire sequence versus doing one at a time.

What am I doing wrong?

**JQuery**

```
$('.grid').on('click',function() {     
  if ($(this).hasClass('16pads'));
  {
    $(this).removeClass('16pads');
    $(this).addClass('36pads'); 
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('36pads'));
  {
    $(this).removeClass('36pads');
    $(this).addClass('64pads');
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('64pads'));
  {
    $(this).removeClass('64pads');
    $(this).addClass('16pads'); 
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just imagine the flow of your method execution:

1. Does it have `16pads`? Yes.
2. Replace `16pads` with `36pads`.
3. Now, does it have `36pads`? Yes.
4. Replace `36pads` with `64pads` etc.

Replace `if` with `else if`:

```
$('.grid').on('click',function() {     
  if ($(this).hasClass('16pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('16pads');
    $(this).addClass('36pads'); 
  }
  else
  if ($(this).hasClass('36pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('36pads');
    $(this).addClass('64pads');
  }
  else
  if ($(this).hasClass('64pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('64pads');
    $(this).addClass('16pads'); 
  }
});
```

Now, it changes class only once and leaves this method.

Comment: Thanks for the response! For some reason I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: @Jeff It looks like you have a syntax error in your code - there should be no `;` after `if`. I have updated my answer, try this one.

Comment: Thanks! It is now working after removing ; after if.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add else,

and i think class name is not good use number start like 16pads :)

```js
$('.grid').on('click',function() {     
  if ($(this).hasClass('t_16pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('t_16pads');
    $(this).addClass('t_36pads'); 
  }

  else if ($(this).hasClass('t_36pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('t_36pads');
    $(this).addClass('t_64pads');
  }

  else if ($(this).hasClass('t_64pads'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('t_64pads');
    $(this).addClass('t_16pads'); 
  }  
});
```

```css
.t_16pads{
  font-size:16px;
 }
 
.t_36pads{
  font-size:36px;
 }
 
.t_64pads{
  font-size:64px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid t_16pads">CLICK HERE</div>
```